# Same equations give different answers : PYTHON

Tags: python, math, python-3.x

I have two arrays: say G[ ][ ] and C[ ][ ].

I process the arrays in the following way:

```
G[i][j] = G[i][j] + 2.0 * C[i][j] * (1.0 - x/y) * z
```

where x, y, z are some variables and i spans(0,100) and j spans(0, 10). So, basically they are large arrays.

I ran the code in python on my Windows computer and on my Linux computer, but I get different results, where the Windows' results are the 'good' results.

**I am not able to find out what makes the math different in Linux and how should I 'tune' the results to match the windows' results.**

**All the data types are float.**

Sample values:

```
PC1: 1.1362725450901805 
PC2: 1.1643972063283112
```

Though on even further computations, the results vary with a huge amount:

```
PC1: -2.something
PC2: 0.something
```

Comment: How large is the difference? Could it just be normal floating point imprecision?

Comment: Can you provide example numbers.

Comment: My guess is different versions of Python, causing different behaviour for the `/` operator. Are you definitely using Python 3 on both?

Comment: And you may want to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for large arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "/" in python 2 is integer division if the arguments are integers, whereas in python 3 "/" is real division. you can get round this by

```
from __future__ import division
```

or by ensuring that at least one argument in every division is a float.

Comment: Gee. Thanks. The answers came out perfectly right. *sigh of relief*

Comment: what is your 'round' function - they way you talk about it is that you have written a "round" function ?

Comment: read https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round or https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round - you could just be suffering from the issues around decimal approximations.

Comment: If accuracy is really important - maybe use the Decimal module - which implements fixed point arithmetic.

Comment: so what is it rounding to ?

Comment: Moved the second issue to another question.

Comment: Add a link your your other question for completeness.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214184/round-function-does-not-work-in-v2-6-6-but-works-in-v3-4-2