# Round Function does not work in v2.6.6, but works in v3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

My round function does not work in linux python 2.6.6, whereas it works fine in Windows 3.4.2
after using the following type of code:

```
Array[i] = round(math.e ** AnotherArray[i], 4)

v.3.4.2:  0.0025999999999999999 => 0.0026
v.2.6.6:  0.0025999999999999999 =>  0.0025999999999999999
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They both work the same, but Python 2.7 and up will round floating point numbers *when printing their `repr`esentations*, in order to not confuse users by the (language- and machine-independent) [limitations of floating point arithmetic](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

The decimal number `0.0026` can't be represented exactly as a binary `float`, so there will always be some rounding error.

If you want less confusion, just `print` the numbers:

```
>>> a = 0.0025999999999999999
>>> b = round(a,5)
>>> b                  # this calls repr(b) 
0.0025999999999999999
>>> print b            # this calls str(b)
0.0026
```

In practice, those rounding errors rarely matter, although you need to be aware of them, especially when comparing for equality.

The following loop *doesn't stop* at 0:

```
x = 1.0
while x != 0:
    print x
    x -= 0.1
```

Why? Let's take a look:

```
>>> x = 1.0
>>> while x != 0:
...     print repr(x)
...     x -= 0.1
...     if x<0: break
...
1.0
0.90000000000000002
0.80000000000000004
0.70000000000000007
0.60000000000000009
0.50000000000000011
0.40000000000000013
0.30000000000000016
0.20000000000000015
0.10000000000000014
1.3877787807814457e-16
```

Therefore, always take `sys.float_info.epsilon` into account:

```
>>> x = 1.0
>>> while abs(x) > sys.float_info.epsilon:
...     print x
...     x -= 0.1
...
1.0
0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
```

Comment: But my 2.6.6 is not even 'printing' it in the rounded form

Comment: Yes, because that behavior was introduced in Python 2.7 (see above).

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to? `0.0026` *cannot* be represented exactly as a floating point number. Just like you can't write the result of `1/3` exactly as a decimal number.

Comment: Ok. So, for those numbers that cannot be represented exactly, the round function will JUST not work?

Comment: Hey Hobbit. I had this same argument a while back. Just give up, round does not round as you would expect in excel. I suggest you try using decimal instead of floats.... For more reading this may help... http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: @HappyHamburger: Excel has the same problem, it just chooses to not display all the decimal places. Just like Python 2.7 and up have chosen to do. Heck, they created an entire movie plot around this (Superman III)...

Comment: So why does my round(1/3, 4) give me 0.3333?

Comment: @HobbitEesmereldatGoldworthy: In Python 2.6, it doesn't. It gives `0.0` because `1/3` is 0 (integer division!) - `round(1.0/3, 4)` gives `0.33329999999999999`

Comment: Ok. After using %g operator, I do get my values printed 'nicely'. Afraid of sounding annoying, but, in my 2.6.6, when I say, print(round(1.0/3), 4), it DOES give me 0.3333. I do get your point. And I wish, I would've have gotten 0.3332999999999 as you say.

Comment: @HobbitEesmereldatGoldworthy: I've updated my answer. `print` already rounds (because it calls `str()`), typing the variable name or entering the calculation directly in the shell doesn't (because it calls `repr()`). So the `%g` formatting operator isn't needed after all.